# Do we gain our reputation back if we undo an accidental down-vote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

I know there is a loss of one reputation when you down-vote a post but the reputation change takes time to show up.

If we accidentally down-vote a post and undo it a few seconds later does the reputation loss undo as well?

Comment: FWIW, that happens to me all the time on mobile when I want to check the vote counts, especially with the stupid new UI that shrinks the available space for the vote total.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but again the reputation change may take time to show up.